# Get shareable link form Mega.nz in command line

Tags: batch-file, command-line, cloud, share

I'm trying to work with mega.nz via command line (batch file), use for it megatools
https://github.com/megous/megatools

Sync work fine, download work fine, but i can't found how to generate shareable link to file on mega. Is there any possible way?

May be use Megacmd, or something else?
https://github.com/meganz/MEGAcmd

Can't find command to share file...

Comment: OK... i found it. 0:-)  MEGAcmd -> "export -a [path]" command.

Answer (score 3):

```
put YouUploadFileName
export -a YouUploadFileName
```

https://github.com/meganz/MEGAcmd/blob/master/UserGuide.md